How to mock composable with vitest?
I'm learning TDD in simple Nuxt.js project. This project is frontend of Laravel API. And what this project does is to implement all Laravel Fortify options. So I'm using external package called nuxt-auth-sanctum. Because Fortify, uses Sanctum.
My goal is to test this middleware, which checks if the user email is verified :
import { defineNuxtRouteMiddleware, navigateTo } from 'nuxt/app'
import type { User } from '~/models/user'
import { useSanctumAuth } from '#imports' // This is here because VS Code has problem recognising Nuxt.js auto-imports

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
  const { user } = useSanctumAuth<User>()

  // List of routes to exclude from this middleware
  const excludedRoutes = [
    '/auth/login',
  ]

  // Check if the current route is in the excluded routes
  if (excludedRoutes.includes(to.path)) {
    return
  }

  // Check if the user's email is verified
  if (user.value && !user.value.email_verified_at) {
    return navigateTo('/auth/verify-email')
  }
})

Here, useSanctumAuth is composable which comes from nuxt-auth-sanctum package. It's role is to return user.
And I want to mock that composable in my test:
import { describe, it, expect, vi, beforeEach } from 'vitest'
import checkEmailVerified from '@/middleware/check-email-verified.global'
import type { RouteLocationNormalized } from 'vue-router'
import { navigateTo } from 'nuxt/app'

vi.mock('nuxt/app', () => ({
  navigateTo: vi.fn(),
  defineNuxtRouteMiddleware: vi.fn((middleware) => middleware),
}))

vi.mock('#imports', async () => ({
  useSanctumAuth: vi.fn(() => ({
    user: {
      value: {
        email_verified_at: null,
      },
    },
  })),
}))

describe('checkEmailVerified middleware', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        vi.clearAllMocks()
    })

    it('should allow access to excluded routes without redirection', async () => {
        const to: RouteLocationNormalized = {
          path: '/auth/login',
        } as RouteLocationNormalized

        const from: RouteLocationNormalized = {
          path: '/',
        } as RouteLocationNormalized

        await checkEmailVerified(to, from) // Error: [vitest] No "useNuxtApp" export is defined on the "nuxt/app" mock. Did you forget to return it from "vi.mock"?

        expect(navigateTo).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
   })
})

When I run the test, I'm getting this error:
[vitest] No "useNuxtApp" export is defined on the "nuxt/app" mock. Did you forget to return it from "vi.mock"?

on that line:
await checkEmailVerified(to, from)

useNuxtApp comes from useSanctumAuth composable, which I want to mock. As I'm aware, mocking composable (in my case) means, that real code is not called but mocked one instead. Then why I'm getting that error? It should'n go inside useSanctumAuth at all. It is mocked to return user.
What am I doing wrong?

How is vitest configured to recognize "#imports"? Did you try to mock nuxt-auth-sanctum directly?

I'm not sure how Vitest recognises "#imports", this is Nuxt auto-import feature. But this row does not have any impact to test. I can remove it or replace it with "import { useSanctumAuth } from '~/node_modules/nuxt-auth-sanctum/dist/runtime/composables/useSanctumAuth'", the app will work but the test did not pass with same error. This row is there because of VS Code, if I remove it (which is perfectly legal in Nuxt) VS Code will complain here: const { user } = useSanctumAuth(), that "Cannot find name 'useSanctumAuth'."

Did you try vi.mock('nuxt-auth-sanctum'? And in case it doesn't work then import it from nuxt-auth-sanctum instead of #import?

Just tried, same thing. vi.mock('nuxt-auth-sanctum' ... and import { useSanctumAuth } from '~/node_modules/nuxt-auth-sanctum/dist/runtime/composables/useSanctumAuth'

It should be import from 'nuxt-auth-sanctum' because '~/node_modules/nuxt-auth-sanctum... would be considered a different, unmocked module. Tried this too?

import { useSanctumAuth } from 'nuxt-auth-sanctum', does not work, because  'nuxt-auth-sanctum' resolves to 'node_modules/nuxt-auth-sanctum/dist/types.d.ts', where there is no exported member 'useSanctumAuth'. The test passes, but the app does not work :)

This sounds like a real problem because nuxt autoimports are an option but not a necessity. Since useSanctumAuth isn't used like a type, it's incorrect that's it's resolved to d.ts. The package itself is ok,  I'd suggest to address this first

Can you try to use the composable mockNuxtImport from the official package @nuxt/test-utils? See the documentation

Thanks @Kapcash! That works. I't seams that I have to use what Nuxt offer first, and then what Vitest offers :)

With the help of @Kapcash, now it works. I have to use what Nuxt offer first and then Vitest.
Here is what I've changed: instead of
vi.mock('#imports', async () => ({...

now I have:
import { mockNuxtImport } from '@nuxt/test-utils/runtime'
....

const mockUser = ref<User | null>(null)
mockNuxtImport('useSanctumAuth', () => {
  return () => ({
    user: mockUser,
  })
})

beforeEach(() => {
        vi.clearAllMocks()
        mockUser.value = null
    })

